# producer consumer condition variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer

I read data from a file and process it in a seperate thread. I am trying to parallelize the data read and processing parts on two threads and using conditional variables with infinite loops.
However, I end up with deadlocks.

```
char totBuf[300000];
unsigned long toLen = 0;
unsigned long lenProc = 0;
void procData()
{
      while(lenProc < totLen)
      {
           //process data from totBuf
           //increment lenProc;
      }
      ready = false;
      if(lenProc >= totLen && totLen > 100000)
      {
            cv.notify_one();
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
            cv.wait(lk, []{return totLen>0 && lenProc<totLen;});
      }
}
void readData()
{
      //declared so that we notify procData only once
      bool firstNot = true;
      while(true)
      {
            //read data into
            //file.read(len);
            //file.read(oBf, len);
            memcpy(&totBuf[totLen], oBf, len);
            //increment totLen
            if(totLen > 10000)
                  cv.notify_one();
            if(totLen > 100000)
            {
                 cv.notify_one();
                 unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
                 cv.wait_for(lk,  []{return !ready;});
                 totLen = 0;
                 firstNot = true;
                 lenProc = 0;
            }
      }     
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    inFile.open(argv[1], ios::in|ios::binary);
    thread prod(readData); 
    thread cons(procSeqMsg); 
    prod.join();
    ready = true;
    cout << "prod joined\n";
    cv.notify_all();
    cons.join();
    cout << "cons joined\n";
    inFile.close();
    return(0);
}
```

Some explanations if it looks weird. Though I have declared totBuf size to 300k but i reset totLen to 0 when its 100k because i read data in chunks from the file where the new chunks could be big. When size reaches 100k I reset totLen to read data at begining of totBuf again.
I notify the consumer first when size reaches 10k so that maximum concurrent processing can be achieved.
This could be a really bad design afaik and am willing to redesign from scratch. What I want is total lockfree implementation but am new to threads hence this is done as a stop-gap/ best I could do right now.

Comment: You could share a queue between the two threads and use the queue to handle the notification by checking if there elements to consume.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have seen examples for `spsc boost` but not sure how can i use this with char data. could you possibly point me to something which handles char buffers?

Comment: You can just use that queue with a `char*` as the type.  In the function that reads the file you create a new `char *` with a size that you want to read.  Read the data into that `char* ` and then push it onto the queue.  In the consumer function you then grab the pointer from the queue and then when you are done you delete it.

Comment: @NathanOliver, great, thanks! Now you've said it looks really simple :). I'll try it. thanks!